# What actually constitutes 'changed' as far as an ItemsSource property is concerned

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, mvvm, custom-controls

I have a custom control which inherits from ItemsControl and so has an ItemsSource property.  In the control I want to know when the itemsSource changes so I have the following code in the controls code file:

```
Shared Sub New()
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(GetType(VtlDataNavigator), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(GetType(VtlDataNavigator)))
    ItemsSourceProperty.OverrideMetadata(GetType(VtlDataNavigator), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Nothing, AddressOf OnItemsSourceHasChanged))
End Sub
```

When I add the control to a form in my test application I bind the ItemsSource like so:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Margin="4"
                Orientation="Vertical">
        <WpfControls:VtlDataNavigator x:Name="MyDataNavigator" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Orders,Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And in the code behind linked to that view I set the Orders property like so:

```
Class MainWindow
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent
        Orders = Context.OrdersList
    End Sub



    Private _orders As C1.Data.ClientView(of OrderHeader)
    Public Property Orders As C1.Data.ClientView(of OrderHeader)
        Get
            Return _orders
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As C1.Data.ClientView(of OrderHeader))
            If (_orders Is Value) Then Return
            _orders = Value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(NameOf(Orders)))
        End Set
    End Property


    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
        'Orders = Context.OrdersList
        'With MyDataNavigator
        '    .ItemsSource = Orders
        'End With
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now my dilemma, and what I don't quite understand is why when the orders property is being specifically set either at the constructor or loaded stage (and at either time it is raising the Orders changed event) it is not triggering the ItemsSource Changed event.  However I can set the Orders property in the constructor and run the code in the loaded event that specifically 'resets' (my choice of word there) the ItemsSource property and lo and behold the items source changed gets fired.

I've tried having no Mode set in the xaml, to Mode = Oneway and Mode=Twoway the latter which I have left in the code illustrated above but this seems to make no difference.

I would like it to be possible for myself and others to use this control in a proper mvvm scenario where in reality the only binding is likely to be in the xaml and where I would have thought that if it was bound to Orders and Orders changes then the ItemsSource changed event would fire.

I suspect that I'm missing something really obvious but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Think about it - the routine you want to establish is "do something when there is a change". You have to find out first if there is indeed a change. When your object becomes alive, the default value is 'nothing'. Even if you set the ItemSource hundred times with 'nothing', you shouldn't expect a 'change'.

Comment: @tagaPdyk  You're correct, had I had the sense to set up the test project exactly as it is intended that it would be used in the real world then I would actually have seen the effect that I wanted to.  Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Once you bind a observable collection you should not create a new or change the observable collection and expect the binding to work.  Best suggestion is to clear the items in the observable collection and add the items in from the new observable collection to the bound observable collection.

Comment: Ken, thanks for your answer. My mistake I believe was in not following the procedure in the test project I built to test the progress of the custom control that would be followed in  real life, as a result of which the Orders collection was never proceeding beyond the value of nothing.  Your point about not abount not creating a new or changed observable collection make me go back and add even more breaks to exactly follow the progress of Orders, once the creation was in a separate view model it worked as it should.